# Non comformable arrays error in R

Tags: arrays, r, matrix

```
numberofusers=75000
numberofitems=65000
number.of.factors=10
# N is a numberofusers*numberofitems sparse Matrix (loaded from a dataset).
#X,Y matrices are already available and have dimensions 
#     (numberofusers,number.of.factors) and 
#(numberofitems,number.of.factors) respectively

ptempuser<-rep(0,numberofitems)
tempuser<-rep(0,numberofitems)
Y.big<-t(Y)%*%Y
for (i in 1:numberofusers) {
   matrixproduct1 <- matrix(0,numberofitems,number.of.factors)
   nonzerolistforthatuser <- which(N[i,]!=0)
   tempuser[nonzerolistforthatuser] <- alpha*N[i,nonzerolistforthatuser]
   ptempuser[nonzerolistforthatuser] <- 1
   matrixproduct1[nonzerolistforthatuser,]   <-tempuser[nonzerolistforthatuser]*Y[nonzerolistforthatuser,]
   finalproductmatrix1 <- matrix(0,number.of.factors,number.of.factors)
   finalproductmatrix1 <- t(Y)[,nonzerolistforthatuser] %*% matrixproduct1[nonzerolistforthatuser,]
   tempuser <- 1+tempuser
   matrixproduct2 <- t(Y)
   matrixproduct2[,nonzerolistforthatuser] <- t(Y)[,nonzerolistforthatuser]*tempuser[nonzerolistforthatuser]

   Agen<-Y.big + finalproductmatrix1
   dim1<-dim(Y.big)
   dim2<-dim(finalproductmatrix1)
   if(dim1[1]!=dim2[1]){
     print(i)
     print(dim1[1])
     print(dim2[1])
    }
   if(dim1[2]!=dim2[2]){
     print(i)
     print(dim1[2])
     print(dim2[2])
     } 

   finalproductmatrix2 <- matrixproduct2[,nonzerolistforthatuser] %*% cbind(ptempuser[nonzerolistforthatuser])
   X[i,] <- (ginv(Y.big+finalproductmatrix1+diag(rep(lambda,number.of.factors))))%*%(finalproductmatrix2)  
}
```

I get the error as 'Error in Y.big + finalproductmatrix1 : non-conformable arrays' . But I even tried doing Agen<-Y.big+ final productmatrix1 inside the function and that has no problem. So surely the dimensions are not causing a problem. Still I get non conformable.
Please tell me what to do. I am stuck on this for hours. I have also checked for the dimension condition and that shows no print results. So I am confused.

Comment: The variable `N` is not defined so the code is not runnable.

Comment: N is a numberofusers*numberofitems matrix.